# How do I run additional JS function after calling location.reload()?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run some code that refreshes the webpage, and THEN does the console log.

The issue is the console.log is happening before the page reload.

```
location.reload();
console.log("test");
```

How do I adjust this to get the desired behavior?

Comment: You can't unless you control the page source itself. The JS context gets destroyed by the page load.

Comment: before to your reload you can use setTimeout to run a function some seconds after.

Comment: @JoseLora once the reload occurs the `setTimeout` will be cleared and no longer exists unfortunately. As for options, it depends on if you have access to a backend (or server side). Then you could have the ability to send a response and then then on the reload the server would be able to send a response with the value string. With only client-side, as @kshetline said, you would need a cookie to pass messages between reloaded pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very act of refreshing a web page ends execution of scripts on that page, apart from what might be called in `onbeforeunload` or `onunload` handlers. Once the reload has actually occurred, no more JavaScript in the pre-reload page can be executed.

If you need to cause something to happen after content has been reloaded, you'll have to use something like a cookie to pass a message to the reloaded page indicating the action you want to take.

Comment: Thanks, this made sense after your explanation. I ultimately got it working using cookies. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score -1):

Use extentions like TamperMonkey to handle your script.